# C# Output wont go to TextBox in a Form

Tags: c#

I can't figure out why the `say()` method is not able to write to TextBox I have on my form called "ConsoleBox". Please Help.

OLD:
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    public void say(string h)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine();
        ConsoleBox.AppendText(h);
    }


    public void richTextBox_ChangedText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                        
        say("Online ...");
        say("What is you Name?");
        string Name = System.Console.ReadLine();
        say("It is truly a pleasure to meet you, Sir {0}" + Name);
    }
}
```

Is this how it should be?
New:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                                
        }

        public void say(string h)
        {                
            ConsoleBox.AppendText(h);
        }



        private void ConsoleBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            say("Online ...");
            say("What is you Name?");
            //string Name = outputbox.AppendText();
            //say("It is truly a pleasure to meet you, Sir {0}" + Name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong as such in your code. It seems size of TextBox is very small and your are not able to see all text. Please try to make it bigger.

Couple of improvements.

You should comment-out or delete lines containing `System.Console` in your testing. I dont think you would be able to see Console window while running it in Debug Mode from VS IDE. Those lines are not playing any roles. Even `System.Console.ReadLine` will not be able to read anything.

First try to run with only below 2 lines:

```
say("Online ...");
say("What is you Name?");
```

Below code works for me:

```
public void say(string h)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine();
    textBox1.AppendText(h);
}

private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    say("Online ...");
    say("What is you Name?");
}
```

Comment: sorry about the "System.Console" my tutorial so far did not tell me how to not use that. i tried doing "WriteLine();" in the say method instead but it didn't, work can you tell me how to rephrase it please

Comment: You have done the write thing that instead of writing to console you will append text to a text box. You can add another `TextBox` and get `Name` from that TextBox. It will enable you to remove `System.Console.ReadLine()` line.

Comment: Sorry please keep the on `textchanged` event on RitchTextBox. It should work now as it works for me with your edited code. If it doesnt work then let me know which version of VS is used by you.

Comment: okay i'll try it after i figure out to recover the solution XD i messed it up a little

Comment: okay so it repeatedly spams the output(how do i fix that), but only after i press any key in the Text box(How do i fix that?). BTW changing the name to "richTextBox" gave me an error so i kept it "ConsoleBox" because that's the name of it

Comment: You should not use 'ConsoleBox` to trap change event and then modify the content as well. You should keep two textboxes. 1 to type value and 2nd where value will be appended. I used two text boxes as `textBox1` and `richTextBox1`

Comment: okay i'll change the names, thanks. But any idea on how to keep it from spamming?